# C++: How do I assign a value from a 2D dynamic array to another 2D dynamic array since 'temp[0][0] = array[0][0]' doesn't work?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, assign

I'm new to c++, and I'm trying to figure out how to get a 2D dynamic array called temp to get values from another 2D dynamic array called array. I couldn't figure out how to assign any values from array to temp because the statement 'temp[0][0] = array[0][0];' doesn't seem to assign the value of array[0][0] which is 1 to temp[0][0]. Instead, temp[0][0] seems to have the same random number in it after 'temp[0][0] = array[0][0]' before any value was assign to temp[0][0]. I tried to assign temp[0][0] to 2 and it works. I don't really know how to exactly assign values from one 2d dynamic array to another. Anyway thanks in advance for helping me out!

```
    ...
    //initializing first 2D dynamic array
    int x=2;
    int y=2;
    int** array = new int*[x];
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++) array[i] = new int[y];

    //initializing second 2D dynamic array
    int new_x=3;
    int new_y=3;
    int** temp = new int*[new_x];
    for(int i=0; i<new_x; i++) temp[i] = new int[new_y];

    //assigning values
    array[0][0] = 1;
    cout << array[0][0] << endl; //output is 1

    //before assigning values to temp[0][0]
    cout << temp[0][0] << endl; //out is a huge random number

    temp[0][0] = array[0][0]; 
    cout << temp[0][0] << endl; //output is the same huge random number


    temp[0][0] = 2;
    cout << temp[0][0] << endl; //output is 2
    ...
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem. Using your code a can not reproduce the error.

Comment: Get rid of the `...` and post a real code example that duplicates the error.  This means all the `#include`'s an `int main()`, etc.

Comment: Compiled and ran this. The assignment `temp[0][0] = array[0][0];` is working as expected in my program. Maybe something around you `...` is the issue. Seconded what the above comments say: write a self contained program that you can compile and run to verify that the problem exists, and then give us that exact code. `#include`s and all.

Comment: Thanks, I've almost rushed to compiler to check this miracle. But there is no miracle :)

Comment: The two arrays have different sizes, are you sure that the weird output you are seeing is about the first element and not some of the others undetermined values?

Comment: Ok, ill try a different compiler program. I was using a program my school was making us use which is putty and winscp.  still dont know why I get this output with tht though, and thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Memory under temp[0][0] is allocated dynamically, therefore that's why you're getting some random (garbage) stuff out of it before assigning 2. When you're assigning 2, the random garbage that's been there gets "overwritten" by a meaningful value, in your case 2 of int type

Comment: They want to know why temp[0][0] = array[0][0] is not 1

Comment: @Tyler Weird, it should work properly

Comment: And it does when I tried

Comment: @Tyler Really? Let me double check

Comment: Ok, ill try a different c++ compiler program to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you posted works exaclty as it should:

First `cout` prints `1` witch is the value of `array[0][0]`.

Second `cout` prints the uninitialized `temp[0][0]`, I compiled it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lQWUQiXavZt3ZcIb), and in this case the value is `0`, but it could be anything.

Third `cout` prints `1` due to the assingment `temp[0][0] = array[0][0]`.

Fourth `cout` prints the value of `2` assigned to `temp[0][0]`.

If there are problems in your code it's not in the posted bit, aside from the fact that you are trying to print an unitialized variable in the second `cout`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried running the code,and the output indeed is 1 after assigning the value.

Comment: This shall be a comment not an answer.

Comment: It's hard to stay silent if you want to point at the problem and have no 50 rep to comment :) But I have to agree :( It should be a comment.

Comment: Yeah :( Not got 50 reps sorry